# Default value for logging level in spring boot will not be taken when using environment variables

Tags: spring, spring-boot

If I want to set the logging level in the yaml configuration via environment variables and the environment variable is not set, the default value will not be taken.

```
logging.level.: ${LOG_LEVEL:INFO}
logging.level.org.hibernate: ${LOG_LEVEL_HIBERNATE:INFO}
```

Output:

```
o.s.b.l.LoggingApplicationListener: Cannot set level: ${LOG_LEVEL:INFO} for ''
o.s.b.l.LoggingApplicationListener: Cannot set level: ${LOG_LEVEL_HIBERNATE:INFO} for 'org.hibernate'
```

This is only when setting the logging level, because in `LoggingApplicationListener#setLogLevels` a PropertyPlaceholderResolver wasn't used. All other properties can be set via env vars and it's belonging default values...

Does anyone solved this, perhaps by overriding the `LoggingApplicationListener`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That wasn't supported in Spring Boot (it is now: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1680).

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! I can't wait to use spring boot 1.1.8!